# remove all text before and after '[img id="123" align="left"]'this and get this imageid and also remove the rest part of this stringi

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to remove all text before and after '[img id="123" align="left"]'this and get this imageid and also remove the other part of this string

mytext:

> "For the past couple of years, the 'Melbourne bounce' sound â€“ a fusion of Dutch-style electrohouse, psy-trance and breaks, pioneered in Australia's second biggest city â€“ has been tearing it up at big EDM raves, finding its way into the sets of Laidback Luke, David Guetta and Calvin Harris. And now THE ONE has brought out a double-pack for any aspiring producers wanting to get in on the Melbourne bounce action.
>   The Melbourne Bounce Bundle, as its imaginatively titled, consists of Melbourne Leads and Bounce Melodies. The former consists of 50 presets for Native Instruments Massive, while the latter contains 100 MIDI loops, geared mostly towards lead synths, and 62 WAV loops from the two demo songs. In total, you get 120MB of sounds to play with.
>   [timg id="55" align="left"]
>   The bundle is available now via Beatport, priced Â£15.95
>   Find out more: Beatport"

```
$patterns = array();
    $patterns[0] = '@(^.*?".*?".*?)\[timg id="(.*?)" align="left"\](.*)@';

$replacements = array(); 
    $replacements[0] = "$2";

preg_replace($patterns, $replacements,$Story_Textarea);
```

here,`storytextarea = my text`

Comment: You need to edit this question for it to make sense. Make a proper title, then ask your question. Add some code for example. Check other questions for guidance

Comment: Looks like you are looking for a PHP-regex-solution – so why did you tag this `CSS`? And your question is not very clear – please go read [ask].

Comment: @Anjali Mirani, it doesn't looks like `css`

Comment: sorry ,css was by mistake.actually tags are preg_replace,php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the result of preg_replace to a variable:

```
$result = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $Story_Textarea);
echo $result; // prints 55 with your sample text.
```